# How to create lines between <span> elements- CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have 4 circles and I want to show lines between these circles, just a way to show that the circles are connected to each other.

```css
.circle {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
</div>
```

I tried adding `<hr/>` after every `<span>` element, however, this is creating lines on next line, any ideas?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9qyvzehw/

Thanks!

Comment: can you add sketch of the expected output

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506642/centering-libefore-content-with-li).

Comment: I was writing an answer when it got closed. I'd do this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/dzagnwfr/ . - or https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/k7amrvy3/

Comment: oh... you meant horizontal line...

Comment: As far as I understand you want a horizontal line through circles. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w4mzfun/) if it can help you.

Comment: awesome, thanks all for your help..got it working!

Comment: According to your requirement I have done that please go through this link https://codepen.io/rajeshkumarsah/pen/pBWzwj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```css
.circle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.line{
  height: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  float: left;
  margin: 14px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```